# Can't copy my key to my authorized key file.

Tags: syntax, file-not-found, key-pair

I am attempting to build my first website and currently trying to make it secure with key pairing so that I can disable password login. However, I am stuck trying to copy my key from my local host to my remote host. 
This is my first time setting up key encryption as I am still new to this all so I am using a step by step guide. Everything has gone smoothly until I reached this step.

Command used on `local host` to cat key into key file on `remote host`:

```
user@localhost:~$ ssh user@example.com "echo `cat ~/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub` >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Result: `cat: /home/user/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub: No such file or directory`

I am wondering if I maybe have misplaced or misused quotations/singlequotes/backticks or maybe an entirely different command is necessary. Perhaps running the command on my remote host would work without the ssh?

Disclaimer: This is a personal project, solely to practice and learn for myself and I'm building with the intention of deleting it and starting over once I finish it. However, while I could go the easy route and just keep password login, I want to understand how the key pairing works and how to set it up for the future.
Any help and input is appreciated, looking to learn as much as I can from this process.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.01 on my local, and CentOS 7 on my remote.

Comment: Just use cat to append to authorized_keys.  You don't need to perform an echo.

Comment: @TomMulkins Thank you, that made the error disappear, however, when I ssh'd to my remote server, it still asks for my standard password and not the pass for the Key I genereated. It only seems to create the authorized_keys file in my local .ssh directory. The guide I'm following makes it seem like I'm trying to put it into the remote hosts .ssh directory. Any idea where I'm going wrong now? Or is this where I should disable password login?

Comment: Try following these instructions and let me know: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: @TomMulkins So skipping the echo ended up being the main problem, but after digging through the secure logs I saw that it was denied by ssh-agent so all I had to do was update the ssh-agent with the key. Now I have automatic login with no password entering required! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome.  Glad you got it sorted out.